# running code in remote process CLR runtime through ICLRRuntimeHost and ExecuteInDefaultAppDomain()

Tags: clr, code-injection

I tried to combine the examples at [coding the wheel](http://www.codingthewheel.com/archives/how-to-inject-a-managed-assembly-dll) and [profiler attach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997942.aspx#attach_example).  Everything seems to go fine, except, when I try to enumerate running assemblies in the remote processes' default appdomain, I don't get the right list.

```
    public class remoteFoo {
    public static int sTest(String message) {
    AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
    Assembly[] assems = currentDomain.GetAssemblies();
    MessageBox.Show("List of assemblies loaded in current appdomain:");
              foreach (Assembly assem in assems)
                  MessageBox.Show(assem.ToString()); //remoteFoo gets listed, but not hostBar.

 return 3;
        }
    }
```

remoteFoo gets listed, but not hostBar. Basically I want to use introspection to run code in the remote process's appdomain.  But it seems that I don't have the right appdomain...

Here is a link to the code I use:  [main.cpp](http://www.autohotkey.net/~tinku99/test/main.cpp)

Comment: It might help to post a little more code (what hostBar is, the actual code you used to load the CLR, etc.) to provide some context to the question.

Comment: sure: http://www.autohotkey.net/~tinku99/test/main.cpp

Comment: So one more thing I'm unclear about: is there a managed assembly called "hostBar", or is that the name of the native exe that is hosting the CLR?